# Set up a postgres database with a specific role without password prompt

Tags: postgresql, role, password

## Context

I have a PostgreSQL server (`localhost:5432`) which holds a database called `my_database`.

I have created long time ago, a simple role which owns this database; `my_user`, different from the `postgres` role;

```
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 my_user   | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

This manually created role does not have an OS equivalent user, like `postgres` does.

I have a bash script to reinitialize `my_database` with a set of schemas and tables (from the `create_db.sql` file);

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
dropdb -U my_user my_database || true
createdb -U my_user my_database --owner=my_user
psql -U my_user -d my_database -h localhost -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -a -f create_db.sql
```

## Issue

Since a few days, this script is asking me 3 times the password for `my_user`. I guess one time per line.
Before that, I was able to run it without any prompt for any password. That was really cool.

The only thing I changed in between was this;
I usually connect to this server using `pgadmin3` with the `postgres` user to checkout what's inside my tables.
In `pgadmin3`, I once set up this server credentials to `my_user` and its password to checkout some differences  with the `postgres` login.
Then, always in `pgadmin3`, I switched back the credentials to `postgres` as they were before.

## Question

I cannot understand why this would have broken something which had since then made my script asking for password...
It may be related to something other, but I really don't know what?

I also tried to set up a `.pgpass` file with this line;

```
localhost:5432:my_database:my_user:my_user_password
```

and changing its access to `0600` as stated in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/libpq-pgpass.html).

But it doesn't seem to be recognized; the bash script is still asking 3 times for `my_user` password.
And, as I (the ubuntu normal OS user, which is *not* the same as the role `my_user` which owns `my_database`) owns this file , I wonder if I should set up permissions to this file to the `postgres` OS user instead?

Anyway, this `.pgpass` file was empty before, when I was able to reset `my_database` without any password prompt. So if I can recover the previous behavior it would be nice, except if this is not a good practice.

Any clue would be appreciated as I'm not much used to database management.

## Information

"PostgreSQL 10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit"

### EDIT

I just noticed that if I set the `.pgpass` file with this content;

```
*:*:*:my_user:my_user_password
```

it works (it stops asking for a password).

But with the database name;

```
*:*:my_database:my_user:my_user_password
```

it doesn't (it keeps asking for a password).

Comment: `dropdb` and `createdb` **do not** connect to the database passed on the command line, so that would be why `*` or a specific dbname in .pgpass have different results. See the `--maintenance-db` option in their manual pages.

Comment: You seems on a right track; the single last `psql` command is actually working with `md5` auth and the complete full line in the `~/.pgpass` file. But this; `dropdb -U my_user --maintenance-db=my_database my_database || true` raises an error; `dropdb: database removal failed: ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database` (nothing else is connected to the db).

Comment: In .pgpass you can allow connections  to the `postgres` database and do not specify `--maintenance-db` in your dropdb and createdb invocations. That would let your script pass without asking for a password.

Comment: Sounds good... But what to specify in the `.pgpass` file the case the `postgres` role is actually using a `peer` auth (based on unix socket)? Setting for example `*:*:*:postgres:*` doesn't work; it still asks for a password for the user `my_user`.

Comment: Then you need to refine the rules in `pg_hba.conf` first. Please ask a new specific question if you need an elaborate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You edited away the problem.

In your comments you say that the database is really `projATX_db`. At least that is what you think. But PostgreSQL translated all unquoted text to lower case, so when you run

```
CREATE DATABASE projATX_db;
```

the database is really called `projatx_db`

Now the entries in the password file are *not* subject to this lower case conversion (that is specific to SQL), so `projATX_db` in the password file does *not* match your database.

Comment: `PGHOST` is and was never set. Local auth is set to `md5` in `pg_hba.conf`. I'd like to keep it so (it's working when setting it to `trust` of course). My `.pgpass` is my home directory but it seems to me it is not read by postgres, even if I `export PGPASSFILE=~/.pgpass` before running my script.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, the contents of the file are wrong. The correct host is *not* `localhost`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't precise that I used your proposed new content for the `~/.pgpass` file.

Comment: From your updates it looks like you made an error with the database name. Is the database really called `my_database`? If not, you should show the real name.

Comment: Hmm, i cannot see (I may have missed something important) what's wrong with the fact that the name in my edit is the same than in the aforementioned commands, such as dropdb and createdb. But indeed, the database is name after a project, such as `projATX_db`. I may then search and replace all occurrences of `my_database` with this specific name in the whole text of this page. Would it change something?

Comment: That's the problem; see my updated answer.

Comment: That's really interesting, but the same issue appears with my `preprod_db` which has no capital letter but still an underscore. Could it also be an issue?

Comment: Underscores are fine. colons and backslashes aren't. Hard to diagnose without knowing the whole truth about your system.